# Load data local infile inside procedure or function in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have to execute load data local infile inside a procedure. I am getting error likes its not supported.

Even inside the procedure i have to prepare a statement and then have to execute statement as the file path is dynamic, even that is not supported.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried anything with the [12.5 String Functions :: LOAD_FILE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) function?.

Comment: @wchiquito l have not worked on load_file() before, but it return a null value if file has an empty value. My file is a csv and it can have empty values.  If you can help me out resolving this issue it would be very greatful